# Переконвертировать функцию Arrow в функцию Declaration

Tags: javascript

```
const getLength = source => source.map(str => str.length);
```

пытаюсь также исправить метод `map` на цикл `for of`

```
let iterat = arr.values();
let lengthNum;
for (const value of iterat) {
    lengthNum = value.length;
    console.log (lengthNum);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

А если копать еще дальше )

```
function getLength (source) {
  return source.map(function(str){
    return str.length
  });
}
```

Без map.

```
function getLength (source) {
  let result = [];
  for( let item of source){
    result.push(item.length)
  }
  console.log(result)
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Я еще пытаюсь заменить map на другой цикл(for of), но что-то не получается

Comment: Дополнил ответ .

Comment: @Марта а в чем заключается смысл этих действия? Есть же готовые методы/функции, почему бы не использовать именно их?

Comment: @dmitriy_vlz Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @MoloF я только начинаю программировать и не все еще получается, а ко всем методам я еще не дошла

Comment: @Марта, посмотрите как реализован полифилл для метода `map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @RomanSklyarov Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
  function getLength (source) {
      return source.map(str => str.length);
  }
```